# Performance hit using CAST in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, performance, type-conversion

We have a SQL generator that emits SQL conditional statements generically for specified fields (which for the sake of discussion: we will label as `myField`).

If `myField` is of type `NVARCHAR`, we can do a comparison of said field against a string like so: `myField = 'foo'`.

However, this does not work for fields of type `NTEXT`.  Thus, we have to do the comparison with a cast:  `CAST(myField as NVARCHAR(MAX)) = 'foo'`.  This will in fact work if `myField` is of type `NVARCHAR` or `NTEXT`.

What is the performance hit of doing the aforementioned cast on a field that is *already* of type `NVARCHAR`?  My hope is that SQL Server is smart enough to dynamically recognize that `myField` is already of type `NVARCHAR` (effectively turning the `CAST` into a no-op).

Comment: A quick note for anyone finding this question: NTEXT (and TEXT and IMAGE) are officially deprecated and due to be removed in some future version of SQL Server (though IIRC they still work in SQL1014), so you should be using NVARCHR(MAX) (or VARCHAR(MAX) or VARBINARY(MAX)) instead. Replacing the NTEXT column with an NVARCHAR(MAX) one in this instance would remove the need for the cast as the comparison can be done directly with that type, and there are other potential efficiency gains here and elsewhere too. Unfortunately you can't index a *(MAX) column, but you can't a TEXT/NTEXT one either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the cast of the column is to exactly the same datatype and length and the seek predicate is a literal it does indeed seem to disregard it or treat it as a no-op and does an index seek on equality.

```
Seek Keys[1]: Prefix: [tempdb].[dbo].[#test].name = Scalar Operator(N'rpc')
```

If the cast of the column is to the same datatype but greater length and the seek predicate is a string literal it causes an index scan. This is obviously to be avoided.

If the cast of the column is to the same datatype and the same or greater length and the seek predicate is a local variable it adds a compute scalar operator to the execution plan. This  calls `GetRangeThroughConvert` and outputs a range.

This range is used to do an index seek and seems pretty efficient

```
Seek Keys[1]: 
Start: [tempdb].[dbo].[#test].name > Scalar Operator([Expr1006]), 
End: [tempdb].[dbo].[#test].name < Scalar Operator([Expr1007])
```

Testing Code

```
SELECT *
 INTO #test
  FROM [master].[dbo].[spt_values]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ixname] ON #test
(
    [name] ASC
)

DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @name = 'rpc'

SELECT name
FROM #test
WHERE CAST(name AS NVARCHAR(35))= @name --Cast the same and local variable

SELECT name
FROM #test
WHERE CAST(name AS NVARCHAR(MAX))=@name --Cast to longer and local variable

SELECT name
FROM #test
WHERE CAST(name AS NVARCHAR(35))='rpc' --Cast the same and literal

SELECT name
FROM #test
WHERE CAST(name AS NVARCHAR(MAX))='rpc' --Cast to longer and literal
```

Answer (score 6):

In general, the `CAST` will kill performance because it invalidates any use of index seeks as Martin Smith's last example shows. Casting to `nvarchar(max)` or to a different length means a different data type: the fact it's all `nvarchar` is irrelevant.

On top of that, the datatype of the right hand side of the compare matters too. If it's a local variable or parameter of a different length then one side will be implicitly `CAST` to the widest of the 2 datatypes (see [datatype precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)).

Basically, if you have a general `CAST` to `nvarchar(max)` it will bollix things up. I would consider fixing the use of `ntext` before I added `CAST` all over.

The conversion may not show in the query plan. See [Paul White's blog article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/07/19/join-performance-implicit-conversions-and-residuals.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Just a note, Casting like this where Datecreated is datetime

```
 Cast (Datecreated as date) = cast(@MydatetimeValue as date)
```

Does not break SQL's ability to use indexes if indexes exist, and if they don't exist, may result in logging a missing index.

Similarly, when casting from `int` to `tinyint` or `bigint` to `int` etc, the cast function does not stop SQL from using indexes IF the optimiser knows that the cast operation does not change the sort order of the 2 comparable datatypes.

Here are a bunch of tests you can run and view actual plan using Adventureworks2008R2

```
select count(*) from Sales.SalesOrderDetail where SalesOrderID = 8 --1
select top 10 * from Sales.SalesOrderDetail where cast(SalesOrderID as tinyint) = 8  --2
select top 10 * from Sales.SalesOrderDetail where cast(SalesOrderID as bigint) = 8  --3
select top 10 SalesOrderID from Sales.SalesOrderDetail where cast(ModifiedDate  as date) = '19780322' --4
select top 10 SalesOrderID from Sales.SalesOrderDetail where convert(date,ModifiedDate) = '19780322'  --5
select top 10 SalesOrderID from Sales.SalesOrderDetail where cast(ModifiedDate as varchar(20)) = '1978'  --6 -- THIS WILL NOT USE INDEX
select  SalesOrderID from Sales.SalesOrderDetail where cast(ModifiedDate  as date) between '19780101' and '19780109'  --7
```

Comment: cast as date can do an index seek but [still has problems](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34052/3690) compared with expressing as a range seek without a cast.