# Type safety in WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, type-conversion

I've spent the most part of yesterday tracking down a strange bug in our PHP/MySQL application and the culprit seems to be a poor query. We have a table like

```
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| foo_id             | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | 
| bar_id             | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | 
| foo_external_id    | varchar(20)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| ...                | ...                  | ...  | ... | ....    | ...   | 
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Running this query

```
select foo_id, foo_external_id
from   foo_bar
where  foo_external_id = 14
and    bar_id = 5
```

returns

```
+-----------+----------------------+
| foo_id    | foo_external_id      |
+-----------+----------------------+
|      4058 | 14df729146edd353000f | 
|      9150 | 14                   | 
+-----------+----------------------+
```

instead of just

```
+-----------+----------------------+
| foo_id    | foo_external_id      |
+-----------+----------------------+
|      9150 | 14                   | 
+-----------+----------------------+
```

Of course the problem is that we are missing quotes around that `14` literal up there, so my question is are `WHERE` conditions supposed to do type-checks or is this another of the MySQL gotchas we all love?

Comment: I think it's one of those annoying MySQL gotchas. (My "favorite" is the behaviour of `WHERE 1`)

Comment: Using statements with ? arguments would solve this problem for you along with making you less susceptible to sql injection.

Answer (score 2):

According to the SQL Standard, numeric values may only be compared with numeric values e.g. an `INTEGER` value can be compared with a `NUMERIC` value by coercing both to `NUMERIC` values.

It sounds like MySQL is not compliant with Standards in this regard. To be fair, most SQL product exhibit similar implicit type coercions and it is encumbent on users to avoid them (in contrast to a strongly type 3GL whose users might expect a compile error!)

Comment: The statement fails with an error message in Oracle and PostgreSQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: do you mean the OP's? i.e. evaluating `'14df729146edd353000f' = 14`? You can add SQL Server to your list. I suspect the mySQL behaviour of evaluating the above to true is based on Microsoft VBA 's [`VAL()` function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/val-function-HA001228931.aspx).

Comment: FYI, SQL Server would bomb on this because of strict rules around data type precedence. I've found MySQL to be quite random about the conversion processes

Comment: @gbn: I tried it with SQL Server and a comparison `varchar_column = 1` worked.

Comment: that's expected. In this case, the 1 is cast to varchar. If you try with @intvar with non-numeric column data it will error. related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9832/performance-hit-using-cast-in-tsql-sql-server

Comment: @gbn: that is at least not expected by me. Oracle and PostgreSQL will **not** allow `where varchar_column = 1`

Comment: SQL Server: `select * from (select '14df729146edd353000f' id) x where id = 14`: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '14df729146edd353000f' to data type int."