# Need to query records based on Date only (Sample Query given)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
sSQL = "
SELECT ordID, ordName, ordDate, ordShipping, ordStateTax, 
       ordHandling, ordTotal, ordDiscount, ordPrivateStatus 
FROM orders 
WHERE (ordStatus = 7)
"
```

I want to display orders that came in yesterday as a daily report script I am building

How would I go about it?

SQL Server 2005

`ordDate` has this format: `2015-01-28 14:58:49.000`

Comment: What is the type of `ordDate`? `datetime` or `char`?

Comment: Its datetime

I just hope its a simple process, my (hunt it down, break it and hack it til it works) skills are basic. LOL

Comment: You already have an answer and it's good ;)

Comment: Ok, but I haven't a clue how to implement Aaron's suggestions. Those statements are unfamilar, probably because I am a simple man at vbscripting and asp (I know I'm behind the times....)

Comment: THis Worked

OrderDate=LEFT(oRS("ordDate"),4)
OrderDate=Replace(OrderDate,"/","")
TodayDate=LEFT(Date(),4)
GetToday=RIGHT(TodayDate,2)
GetYesterday=RIGHT(Orderdate,2)

IF GetToday - GetYesterday = 1 THEN

Comment: @Robert I think that is quite possibly the *worst* way to do that. Riding a tricycle to work "works" but it's going to take me all day. Other methods not only work, but they *work better*.

Comment: @AaronBertrand as a dedicated Tricyclist I am offended.

Answer (score 5):

An open-ended range is the safest in terms of granularity and sargability, and being immune to underlying data type changes:

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME;
SET @today = DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'20000101',GETDATE()),'20000101');

SELECT ... WHERE ordDate >= DATEADD(DAY,-1,@today)
             AND ordDate < @today;
```

You may get suggestions for other creative ways to find the rows from yesterday, but they'll be less safe and/or slower. You will probably be suggested things like this:

```
WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(10), ordDate, 112) = CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112);
-- not sargable! Will cause a table/index scan even if there is an index on ordDate

WHERE ordDate BETWEEN <yesterday at mignight> AND <yesterday at 23:59:59.997>
-- unsafe! Will break if variables or underlying columns change data types
```

Some links:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- [What is the most efficient way to trim time from datetime?](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime)

*On that last one, pay attention to the performance graphs, particularly how well the open-ended range does.*

When you move to SQL Server 2008 or better, you can also consider the easier `CONVERT(DATE` approach, since this is one of the very few isolated scenarios where applying a function to a column is still sargable. However, you should also read this:

- [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/1186)

To create a procedure for this, in SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.myreport
  @ReportDate DATETIME = NULL
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- report on yesterday if parameter is NULL:
  SET @ReportDate = COALESCE(@ReportDate, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()));

  -- remove time from datetime, in case time is passed:
  SET @ReportDate = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '20000101', @ReportDate), '20000101');

  SELECT ordID, ordName, ordDate, ordShipping, ordStateTax, 
    ordHandling, ordTotal, ordDiscount, ordPrivateStatus 
  FROM dbo.orders 
  WHERE (ordStatus = 7)
    AND orderDate >= @ReportDate 
    AND orderDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @ReportDate);
END
GO
```

Now in your ASP code, after opening `oConn`, you do something like this:

```
set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.Activeconnection = oConn
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.myreport"
cmd.commandType = 4 'adCmdStoredProc
dateParam = date()
cmd.parameters.Append ccmd.CreateParameter("ReportDate", adDate, 1, 0, dateParam)
set oRS = cmd.execute()
do while not oRS.eof 
  ...
```

Sorry, my classic ASP is rusty, so you may have to make adjustments. Thankfully, there are dozens and dozens of sites out there that include tutorials on using connection, command and recordset objects in classic ASP.

Comment: I apologize because I need some hand-holding here. Here's the beginning part of my page. 

I am not familiar with "DECLARE" statements

Dim oConn, oRS, sSQL
Set oConn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set oRS=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oConn.Open(sDSN)
             
sSQL = "SELECT ordID, ordName, ordDate, ordShipping, ordStateTax, ordHandling, ordTotal, ordDiscount, ordPrivateStatus FROM orders WHERE (ordStatus = 7)"

oRS.open sSQL, oConn,1,3

'first of all determine whether there are records
If Not oRS.EOF Then
Do While not oRS.eof

Comment: @Robert I suggest using stored procedures instead of dumping ad hoc SQL in classic ASP code. That said, you should be able to put exactly what I wrote inside the same SQL string and pass it to your conn object...