# Datetime as date only

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

I understand SQL Server 2005 doesn't support `DATE` and so casting a datetime as a date is not possible.

What I want to do is list all records with a datetime within an entire day of the current week.

So I need all records created on Monday of current week ignoring the timestamp. Currently I am using the below, which does show Monday-Friday of current week, but includes the timestamp, which means I'll see different output depending on when the query is run:

```
set datefirst 1

select 
    DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), CONVERT( DATETIME, GETDATE())) as Monday,
    DATEADD(day, 2 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), CONVERT( DATETIME, GETDATE())) as Tuesday,
    DATEADD(day, 3 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), CONVERT( DATETIME, GETDATE())) as wednesday,
    DATEADD(day, 4 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), CONVERT( DATETIME, GETDATE())) as Thursday,
    DATEADD(day, 5 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), CONVERT( DATETIME, GETDATE())) as Friday
```

Can anyone assist?

My expected output would be a column for each day of the current week, where the week starts on Monday (i.e.: Datefirst 1). Ultimately I'm going to use it in a case statement like:

```
CASE
WHEN DateColumn >= DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), CONVERT( DATETIME, GETDATE())) and DateColumn < DATEADD(day, 2 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), CONVERT( DATETIME, GETDATE()))
THEN IntegerColumn
ELSE 0
END AS Monday
```

...Repeating for each day of the week. I need to accommodate for IntegerColumn values which are added throughout Monday. If no DateColumn entries occur within the hours of Monday, a zero is displayed.

Comment: you want 1 row with a column for each day. ie today would be in column Thursday with value 2016-02-11 00:00:00.000 ? Perhaps expected output would help

Comment: I have added a complete sample to the answer and it should cover what you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Today's date is 2016-02-11 and this query returns `2016-02-11 00:00:00.000`:

```
SELECT curDay = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

It can then be included into the `DATEADD` statement:

```
SELECT curDay = GETDATE()
    , DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(weekday, getdate()) + DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) as Monday
    , DATEADD(day, 2 - DATEPART(weekday, getdate()) + DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) as Tuesday
    , DATEADD(day, 3 - DATEPART(weekday, getdate()) + DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) as wednesday
    , DATEADD(day, 4 - DATEPART(weekday, getdate()) + DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) as Thursday
    , DATEADD(day, 5 - DATEPART(weekday, getdate()) + DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) as Friday
```

This will give this output:

```
curDay                  | Monday                    | Tuesday                   | Wednesday                 | Thursday                  | Friday
2016-02-11 11:54:24.947 | 2016-02-08 00:00:00.000   | 2016-02-09 00:00:00.000   | 2016-02-10 00:00:00.000   | 2016-02-11 00:00:00.000   | 2016-02-12 00:00:00.000
```

This query returns Sunday's date (`2016-02-06` this week):

```
SELECT Sunday = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()) - DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()), 0)
```

It can be used with this query and it gives the same output:

```
SELECT curDay
    , DATEADD(day, 1, Sunday) as Monday
    , DATEADD(day, 2, Sunday) as Tuesday
    , DATEADD(day, 3, Sunday) as wednesday
    , DATEADD(day, 4, Sunday) as Thursday
    , DATEADD(day, 5, Sunday) as Friday
FROM (SELECT Sunday = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()) - DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()), 0)) as cd
```

For records with a date on Monday, this query can be used:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE colDate >= DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(weekday, getdate()) + DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) 
    AND colDate < DATEADD(day, 2 - DATEPART(weekday, getdate()) + DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

It outputs rows where the date is bigger or equal to Monday at 00:00 and before Tuesday at 00:00.

It is better to use `date >= '20160101 00:00' and date < '20160102 00:00'` than `BETWEEN`. See: [Why does my query search datetime not match?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108287/why-does-my-query-search-datetime-not-match/112956#112956)

### Full sample ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57998/9/1)):

```
CREATE TABLE test(id int, [date] datetime)

INSERT INTO test values(1, '2016-02-07 23:23')
INSERT INTO test values(2, '2016-02-08 01:01')
INSERT INTO test values(3, '2016-02-08 12:00')
INSERT INTO test values(4, '2016-02-08 23:23')
INSERT INTO test values(5, '2016-02-09 00:00')

DECLARE @date datetime = '2016-02-11 12:34'
set datefirst 1

-- Query 1
SELECT id, [date]
    , IntegerColumn = CASE WHEN [date] >= DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(weekday, @date) + DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @date), 0) 
            AND [date] < DATEADD(day, 2 - DATEPART(weekday, @date) + DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @date), 0)
        THEN IntegerColumn
        ELSE 0
    END
FROM test

-- Query 2
SELECT id, [date], IntegerColumn
FROM test
WHERE [date] >= DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(weekday, @date) + DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @date), 0) 
    AND [date] < DATEADD(day, 2 - DATEPART(weekday, @date) + DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @date), 0)
```

#### Query 1:

```
id  | date                      | IntegerColumn
1   | 2016-02-07 23:23:00.000   | 0
2   | 2016-02-08 01:01:00.000   | 2
3   | 2016-02-08 12:00:00.000   | 3
4   | 2016-02-08 23:23:00.000   | 4
5   | 2016-02-09 00:00:00.000   | 0
```

#### Query 2:

```
id  | date                      | IntegerColumn
2   | 2016-02-08 01:01:00.000   | 2
3   | 2016-02-08 12:00:00.000   | 3
4   | 2016-02-08 23:23:00.000   | 4
```

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'curDay'. for the first query

Comment: answer has been updated/fixed

Comment: If I wanted all the records created Monday, can't I use: select * from TABLENAME where DATECOLUMN Between DATEADD(day, 2 - DATEPART(weekday, getdate()) + DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)
and DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(weekday, getdate()) + DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) ? Doesnt seem to work

Comment: see update. it is usualy a bad idea to use between for date. date >= 20150101 00:00 and date < 20150102 00:00 is better.

Comment: Magnificent, thank you very much for your thorough answer Julien. This is exactly what I needed. I had never dealt with SQL 2005 in this way before so your answer has been extremely helpful.