# Optimized date compare in WHERE clause, convert or datediff=0?

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

In my query I am comparing two dates in the `WHERE` clause

once using `CONVERT`:

```
CONVERT(day,InsertedOn) = CONVERT(day,GETDATE())
```

and another using `DATEDIFF`:

```
DATEDIFF(day,InsertedOn,GETDATE()) = 0
```

Here are the execution plans

For 1st one using `CONVERT`
[image]

For 2nd one using `DATEDIFF`
[image]

The datatype of `InsertedOn` is `datetime`.

Which one is more optimized?

Comment: Shouldn't those two be `CONVERT(date, ...)` ?

Answer (score 7):

Instead, try

```
WHERE InsertedOn>=CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AND
      InsertedOn<DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
```

This expression is [sargable](http://sqlsunday.com/2014/01/19/sargable-expression-performance/) which is what you want for optimum performance. Like @Mikael indicates, you would do well to design one of your indexes so that `InsertedOn` is the first column, and that all the other columns used in the query are included in the index. If you have lots of columns in the query, using the table's clustered index is probably best. Read up on [covering indexes](http://sqlsunday.com/2013/02/24/covering-indexes/).

Comment: Martin Smith has a great answer on a related question: [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea/34052#34052)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ thanks, I just learned something! :)

Answer (score 2):

Would it not be better to have the dates as variables so you only have to get them once before the query?

```
DECLARE @Today DATE
DECLARE @Tomorrow DATE
SET @Today = GETDATE()
SET @Tomorrow = DATEADD(day,1,GETDATE())

SELECT FROM <Table>
WHERE InsertedOn >= @Today
AND InsertedOn < @Tomorrow
```