# How can I improve speed of select?

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I have a table set up like this:

The DB has 10B rows.

```
CREATE TABLE [Tick].[X_H](
       [utcDT] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
       [Symbol] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
       [Bid] [float] NULL,
       [Ask] [float] NULL,
       [BidSize] [float] NULL,
       [AskSize] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] 


ALTER TABLE [Tick].[X_H] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Master] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
       [utcDT] ASC,
       [Symbol] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

I want to select a single day's worth of data for a particular Symbol. I am using:

```
SELECT *  
FROM [Tick].[X_H] 
WHERE [Symbol] = 'DONKEY' 
AND CONVERT(Date, [utcDT]) = CONVERT(Date,'2011-01-02');
```

This takes 3 times longer than reading the same data from a binary file and deserialising it. Binary read is 42ms and SQL read is 115ms.

What might I try to speed it up?

---

The suggestion was made to create a separate [Date] column, which I have and I added 2 indexes.

```
ALTER TABLE [Tick].[FX_HS] ADD [Date] DATE NULL;
UPDATE [Tick].[X_H] SET [Date] = CONVERT(Date,[utcDT])
CREATE INDEX I_Date ON [Tick].[X_H] ([Date]); 
CREATE INDEX I_SymbolDate ON [Tick].[X_H] ([Symbol],[Date]);
```

And I am using query:

```
SELECT *  FROM [Tick].[X_H] WHERE [Symbol] = 'DONKEY' AND [Date] = '2011-01-02';
```

But it takes approximately the same amount of time!

---

#### Execution plan

[Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryOhU6Hqe)

```
Query 1: Query cost(relative to batch): 100%
SELECT * FROM [Tick][X_H] WHERE [Symbol]=@1 AND [Date]=@2
```

[image]

---

As Martin Smith suggested:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

DECLARE @utcDT DATETIME2(7)
DECLARE @Symbol NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Bid FLOAT
DECLARE @Ask FLOAT
DECLARE @BidSize FLOAT
DECLARE @AskSize FLOAT
DECLARE @Date DATE

SELECT @utcDT = utcDT,
       @Symbol = Symbol,
       @Bid = Bid,
       @Ask = Ask,
       @BidSize = BidSize,
       @AskSize = AskSize,
       @Date = Date
FROM   Tick.X_H
WHERE  ( Symbol = 'DONKEY' )
       AND ( Date = '2011-01-02' )
```

This takes:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 47 ms,  elapsed time = 43 ms.
```

Comment: The execution plan looks pretty optimal and the majority of the time is spent transferring the data to the client and waiting for the client to process it. Do you really need `*`? You already know the value for symbol as that is in the initial query and you are returning it in all 166,000 rows.

Comment: @MartinSmith Actually, you put me on the right path! I was using LIKE to find [Date], when I changed to = the query ran very much faster.

Answer (score 8):

Your `where` condition that checks for equality for `utcdt` converted to a date is SARGable, but uses a [dynamic seek](http://web.archive.org/web/20170303101108/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/01/18/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.aspx).

> The problem is that these hidden implicit conversions can result in inaccurate cardinality and distribution estimations at any stage of the plan.  So, even if you get a seek, the plan might be way off overall. - [Dynamic Seeks and Hidden Implicit Conversions - Paul White](http://web.archive.org/web/20170303101108/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/01/18/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.aspx)

Try converting your `where` condition to an explicit range and see if there is any improvement:

```
select *
from Tick.X_H
where Symbol = 'donkey'
  and utcdt >= convert(datetime2(7),'20110102')
  and utcdt <  convert(datetime2(7),'20110103')
```

Based on [this answer by Martin Smith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34052/43889) the explicit range may reduce unnecessary reads.

References:

- [Dynamic Seeks and Hidden Implicit Conversions - Paul White](http://web.archive.org/web/20170303101108/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/01/18/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.aspx)
- [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)
- [SARGable functions in SQL Server - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Actually, that was how I coded it first. It is just as slow I am afraid. I updated my question with another approach, but again that fails to help too.

Comment: @ManInMoon did you have an index on `(symbol, utcdt)` when you tried this?