# Speed up an aggregate query on an 11 million row table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, query-performance

I have a query that I want to speed up:

```
SELECT 
  sum(case when FlagDTD = 1 then Success else 0 end)   as SuccessDTD
, sum(case when FlagDTD = 1 then [Error] else 0 end)   as ErrorDTD
, round(sum(case when FlagDTD = 1 then Success else 0 end) * 100.0 / sum(FlagDTD),2) 
    as RateDTD
, sum(case when FlagYTD = 1 then Success else 0 end)   as SuccessYTD
, sum(case when FlagYTD = 1 then [Error] else 0 end)   as ErrorYTD
, round(sum(case when FlagYTD = 1 then Success else 0 end) * 100.0 / sum(FlagYTD),2)  
    as RateYTD
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      CASE WHEN Message = 'OK'  then 1 else 0 end as Success
    , CASE WHEN Message <> 'OK'  then 1 else 0 end as [Error]    
    , CASE WHEN DateCreated > 
      dateadd(HOUR, datediff(hh,GetUTCDate(), GetDate())*-1,  DATEADD(yy,
        DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)) then 1 else 0 end as FlagYTD
    , CASE WHEN DateCreated > 
      dateadd(HOUR, datediff(hh,GetUTCDate(), GetDate())*-1 , 
        convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 101)) then 1 else 0 end as FlagDTD
    FROM
      [Channels4].[dbo].[NotificationResult]
) Cnts
```

I thought maybe I could create a view or indexed view based on the subquery. However, upon testing I can't create an indexed view because "the view uses an implicit conversion from string to datetime or smalldatetime".

I tried using a traditional view, but that gave no performance enhancement at all. My next thought would be to maybe rewrite the entire query. What are everyone's thoughts?

Plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJqGY7iZW

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NotificationResult]
(
    [IdNotificationResult] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationGuid] [nvarchar](48) NOT NULL,
    [MessageGuid] [nvarchar](48) NOT NULL,
    [IdNotificationResultTypeStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MessageStatusCode] [int] NULL,
    [Message] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [ExceptionStatusCode] [int] NULL,
    [ExceptionMessage] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Subject] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [From] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IdCreatedBy] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [IdLastUpdatedBy] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DateLastUpdated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_NotificationResult] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
    [IdNotificationResult] 
  )
);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NotificationResult_DateMessage] 
  ON [dbo].[NotificationResult] ( [DateCreated] ASC ) INCLUDE ( [Message]);
```

Doing a quick count for YTD, and DTD, I get this number for both: 11739267. The number of rows that are 'OK': 11782564.

Comment: Are you trying to find a way to scan a whole table to generate aggregates without actually scanning the whole table? (Also, traditional views are not really for performance at all, and [indexed views have a much narrower set of use cases than most folks assume](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-wrong-optimizations/#opt5).) Can you post the whole table structure and the existing indexes? Also, we know how many rows in the table, roughly what % are >= DTD and YTD?

Comment: You're just using strings to strip the time part from getdate()? Use `convert(date...)` instead?

Comment: Aaron, thanks for your response! Duh, I didn't even think of that, now I feel dumb haha I guess it just is what it is. My boss was hoping there was a way to make it less intensive.

Comment: @JamesZ just remember that [this can lead the optimizer astray](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea).

Comment: Ok, so almost all of the rows are from this year? Also why not just store the data as UTC so you don't have to account for time zone difference? And what happens when you run this query and include data from both DST and non-DST? Your boundary may be off by an hour (or less than an hour for certain time zone data). Finally, the PK isn't the only index on the table, can you script those as well?

Comment: Also, since `GetDate()` and `GetUTCDate()` are non-deterministic, which means you would not be able to use them in an indexed view anyway.

Comment: @John The way I see it, those wouldn't be materialized in the indexed view, they would be used in the where clause against the indexed view.

Comment: All right, so almost all the rows meet your where clause for the date range, and almost all of the rows meet your where clause for the 'OK'...

Comment: Well that makes this a relatively easy script then. Now I just have to convince my friends over in development :)

Comment: Wait a sec - did you say that you get the same count for the rows that were added today (FlagDTD) and for the rows added this year (FlagYTD)? That sounds fishy, to me.

Comment: Shouldn't you ignore the records prior to this YTD??????? that might be VERY much faster. WHERE DateCreated > (YTDDate)

Comment: I suggest that regardless of performance you first identify and fix the "the view uses an implicit conversion from string to datetime or smalldatetime" issue. It's not an error, just something that can impact performance and randomly break your code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As written you technically haven't asked a question here. I assume that you want to improve the performance of your query, but keep in mind that defining an acceptable response time is sometimes an important part of performance tuning. If a query runs once per day and takes a minute to finish is it really worth 8 hours of your time to make it run in 1 second?

More important than performance is correctness. It doesn't matter so much how long the query takes if it returns the wrong results, although of course taking a long time to return the wrong results is worse than taking a short time to return the wrong results. Depending on your time zone the UTC conversion stuff might not work out as you expected it. If there's any data affected by daylight savings time then you can't use the current hour difference between local time and UTC time to convert old data.

Setting all of that aside, I'm going to try to show you a few ways to speed up the query in the question. You have a covering index which is a good start, especially because it avoids reading the unrelated blob data. However there are still ways to speed up the query. I'm deliberately ignoring the clues that you gave about data distribution because I want to make this a more general answer that could help others and perhaps could be more helpful to you if your data changes in the future.

I mocked up 10 million rows with half of them having "OK" for the message and the other half having a long string. The dates are spread out over a few years. **WARNING: this code takes up around 60 GB of space and ran in around 10 minutes on my machine.**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NotificationResult]
(
    [IdNotificationResult] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Message] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreatedUTC] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Filler] VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_NotificationResult] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
    [IdNotificationResult] 
  )
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[NotificationResult] WITH (TABLOCK) ([Message], [DateCreated], [DateCreatedUTC], [Filler])
SELECT CASE WHEN RN % 2 = 1 THEN 'OK' ELSE REPLICATE('Z', 3000) END
, DATEADD(SECOND, 11 * RN, '20140101')
, CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, 11 * RN, '20140101') AS DATE)
, REPLICATE('FILLER', 166)
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP (10000000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
    FROM master..spt_values t1
    CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
    CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t3
) t;

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NotificationResult_DateMessage] 
  ON [dbo].[NotificationResult] ( [DateCreated] ASC ) INCLUDE ( [Message]);
```

If I run the query in the question I get the same query plan as you. It took 38 seconds. Here are some performance stats for the execution:

> Table 'NotificationResult'. Scan count 5, logical reads 2509562, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 2499799
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 20626 ms,  elapsed time = 37663 ms.

The first opportunity to improve performance is that you have an implied `WHERE` clause predicate in your `CASE` statements. The query optimizer isn't smart enough to realize that any rows from previous years won't contribute to the totals. We know that 24 hours will always be longer than the difference between local time and UTC time so adding a filter like this shouldn't change the results:

```
WHERE DateCreated > DATEADD(DAY, -1, dateadd(YEAR, datediff(YEAR, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

Now instead of reading and aggregating 10 million rows from the index, SQL Server only has to process 1.4 million rows. The savings that you get with this optimization will depend on how the data is distributed in the plan. If all of your data is in the current year then performance won't improve yet. For my data, the query now finishes in 5 seconds and performance is greatly improved:

> Table 'NotificationResult'. Scan count 5, logical reads 352033, physical reads 1, read-ahead reads 350073
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 3062 ms,  elapsed time = 5354 ms.

[image: first plan]

We can do better than that. We're storing a `VARCHAR(MAX)` column in the index when really all that we need to know is if the column value matches "OK" or not. Without changing the table definition we can create smaller indexes to seek or scan against by creating three filtered indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NotificationResult_Date_OK] 
  ON [dbo].[NotificationResult] ( [DateCreated] ASC )
  WHERE [Message] = 'OK';

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NotificationResult_Date_NOT_OK] 
  ON [dbo].[NotificationResult] ( [DateCreated] ASC )
  WHERE [Message] <> 'OK';

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_NotificationResult_Date_NULL] 
  ON [dbo].[NotificationResult] ( [DateCreated] ASC )
  WHERE [Message] IS NULL;
```

The idea here is that these indexes have the data that we need but are much smaller on disk than the existing `IX_NotificationResult_DateMessage` index. Getting the query optimizer to use the filtered indexes required a query rewrite and an index hint (not sure why). Here's one way to rewrite the query:

```
SELECT 
  sum(case when FlagDTD = 1 then Success else 0 end)   as SuccessDTD
, sum(case when FlagDTD = 1 then [Error] else 0 end)   as ErrorDTD
, round(sum(case when FlagDTD = 1 then Success else 0 end) * 100.0 / sum(FlagDTD),2) 
    as RateDTD
, sum(case when FlagYTD = 1 then Success else 0 end)   as SuccessYTD
, sum(case when FlagYTD = 1 then [Error] else 0 end)   as ErrorYTD
, round(sum(case when FlagYTD = 1 then Success else 0 end) * 100.0 / sum(FlagYTD),2)  
    as RateYTD
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      Success
    , [Error]    
    , CASE WHEN DateCreated > 
      dateadd(HOUR, datediff(hh,GetUTCDate(), GetDate())*-1,  DATEADD(yy,
        DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)) then 1 else 0 end as FlagYTD
    , CASE WHEN DateCreated > 
      dateadd(HOUR, datediff(hh,GetUTCDate(), GetDate())*-1 , 
        convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 101)) then 1 else 0 end as FlagDTD
FROM
    (
    SELECT 1 Success, 0 Error, DateCreated 
    FROM
    [dbo].[NotificationResult] WITH (INDEX (IX_NotificationResult_Date_OK))
    WHERE DateCreated > DATEADD(DAY, -1, dateadd(YEAR, datediff(YEAR, 0, getdate()), 0))
    AND [Message] = 'OK'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 0 Success, 1 Error, DateCreated 
    FROM
    [dbo].[NotificationResult] WITH (INDEX (IX_NotificationResult_Date_NOT_OK))
    WHERE DateCreated > DATEADD(DAY, -1, dateadd(YEAR, datediff(YEAR, 0, getdate()), 0))
    AND [Message] <> 'OK'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 0 Success, 1 Error, DateCreated 
    FROM
    [dbo].[NotificationResult] WITH (INDEX (IX_NotificationResult_Date_NULL))
    WHERE DateCreated > DATEADD(DAY, -1, dateadd(YEAR, datediff(YEAR, 0, getdate()), 0))
    AND [Message] IS NULL
    ) t
) Cnts;
```

Now the query finishes in less than a second:

> Table 'NotificationResult'. Scan count 10, logical reads 3874, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 2499 ms,  elapsed time = 890 ms.

(the plan below is missing one of the indexes)

[image: second plan]

It's true that we read more rows from the indexes than before but the indexes are in total about 100 times smaller than the original index.

If that query still isn't fast enough you can consider an indexed view. If you have a UTC date column in the table then it is straightforward to create a view which is eligible to be indexed:

```
CREATE VIEW [NotificationResult_indexed]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
 [DateCreatedUTC]
, COUNT_BIG(*) AS CNT_BIG
, SUM(CASE WHEN Message = 'OK'  then 1 else 0 end) as Success
, SUM(CASE WHEN Message IS NULL OR Message <> 'OK'  then 1 else 0 end) as [Error]   
FROM dbo.[NotificationResult]
GROUP BY [DateCreatedUTC];

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CLU_NotificationResult_indexed   
    ON [NotificationResult_indexed] ([DateCreatedUTC]);  
GO
```

I believe that this query roughly captures your intent although I probably got some details wrong:

```
SELECT 
  sum(case when FlagDTD = 1 then Success else 0 end)   as SuccessDTD
, sum(case when FlagDTD = 1 then [Error] else 0 end)   as ErrorDTD
, round(sum(case when FlagDTD = 1 then Success else 0 end) * 100.0 / sum(FlagDTD),2) 
    as RateDTD
, sum(case when FlagYTD = 1 then Success else 0 end)   as SuccessYTD
, sum(case when FlagYTD = 1 then [Error] else 0 end)   as ErrorYTD
, round(sum(case when FlagYTD = 1 then Success else 0 end) * 100.0 / sum(FlagYTD),2)  
    as RateYTD
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      Success
    , [Error]    
    , CASE WHEN [DateCreatedUTC] > dateadd(YEAR, datediff(YEAR, 0, getdate()), 0)
       then 1 else 0 end as FlagYTD
    , CASE WHEN [DateCreatedUTC] > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
       then 1 else 0 end as FlagDTD
    FROM
      [dbo].[NotificationResult_indexed]
      WHERE [DateCreatedUTC] > dateadd(YEAR, datediff(YEAR, 0, getdate()), 0)
) Cnts;
```

It finishes in 66 ms:

> Table 'NotificationResult_indexed'. Scan count 1, logical reads 7, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 66 ms.

[image: third plan]

Comment: This was amazing and thorough. Thank you so much for taking the time and clearly explaining each step in the process.

Answer (score 1):

It always pleasure to read Joe Obbish.

For Message column you can store 1= 'OK',0=not ok,if you can.

else you have to create filtered index like Joe suggested.

you can store date logic in variable,it will make the script shorter,readable and may be boost performance.

I think you can select all record since "yesterday",which will include all record of yesterday+today.I think you need only this much record for your desire output.

I just tried rewriting your query,understadn the approach and try correcting minor mistake.Filtered index as suggested by Joe.

```
    DECLARE @TodayDate DATETIME = dateadd(HOUR, datediff(hh, GetUTCDate(), GetDate()) * - 1
                                , DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, getdate()), 0))

DECLARE @YesterdayDate DATETIME = dateadd(HOUR, datediff(hh, GetUTCDate(), GetDate()) * - 1
                                , convert(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 101))

SELECT sum(CASE 
            WHEN DateCreated > @YesterdayDate
                AND Message = 'OK'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS SuccessDTD
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN DateCreated > @YesterdayDate
                AND Message <> 'OK'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS ErrorDTD
    ,round(sum(CASE 
                WHEN DateCreated > @YesterdayDate
                    AND Message = 'OK'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END) * 100.0 / sum((
                CASE 
                    WHEN DateCreated > @YesterdayDate
                        THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END
                )), 2) AS RateDTD
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN DateCreated > @TodayDate
                AND Message = 'OK'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS SuccessYTD
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN DateCreated > @TodayDate
                AND Message <> 'OK'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS ErrorYTD
    ,round(sum(CASE 
                WHEN DateCreated > @TodayDate
                    AND Message = 'OK'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END) * 100.0 / sum((
                CASE 
                    WHEN DateCreated > @TodayDate
                        THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END
                )), 2) AS RateYTD
FROM [Channels4].[dbo].[NotificationResult] WITH (NOLOCK)
where DateCreated>=@YesterdayDate
```